# Tampermonkey Javascript Set Attribute to Class Name

Tags: javascript

I'm having some issues setting an attribute to my class name `m-date-entry__day-field`.

This works: `document.getElementById("create-password").setAttribute("value", "ye345s345");`, but only supports Id.

I have tried getElementByClassName, without any success.

Element:
`<input class="m-date-entry__day-field" type="number" name="day" min="1" max="31" pattern="\b^(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$\b" value="" placeholder="DD" required="" data-date="" data-date-day="" data-test="date-entry-day" tabindex="4" autocomplete="bday-day">`

So my end goal is just wanting to set the attribute "1".

Any ideas why `document.getElementByClassName("m-date-entry__day-field").setAttribute("value", "1");`

Comment: check console error and then try to fix it

Comment: it is getElementsByClassName not getElementByClassName

Comment: why does the OP not make use of _document.getElement**s**ByClassName_ or even  [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) and/or [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) ... in addition the OP most probably has to set the `value` directly and not via `setAttribute ` ... `document.getElementsByClassName("m-date-entry__day-field")[0].value = 1`